# Good learning resources for JNDI implementation (JBoss 5)

Tags: jndi, jboss5.x

I have been working with JavaEE/EJB3 web apps for about half a year now. Until recently, I haven't had to touch a lot of the behind-the-scenes stuff, just the meat of the code. I have been wrestling with JNDI problems, and though I've solved a couple of them, I'm pretty much just doing the whole cargo cult copy-paste routine. It would really help me to better understand JNDI; my understanding of it right now can be summarized as "it's that thing these classes sometimes do to find other classes."

My question is, has anyone had success learning JNDI/EJB3/related topics from a book or online content? I've googled for it but the stuff that comes up is old or specific to a certain framework I'm not using. I'm looking for something that's either JBoss-specific or generic enough to be useful anyway.